# dPad Game Controller in tvOS using Publisher to get x-Axis and y-Axis values

Tags: swift, tvos, publisher, siri-remote

I'm trying to read the X- and Y-Axis values of the Siri-Remote-Control on my appleTV Device.

It works fine if I use a "valueChangeHandler" on the dPad.

I was looking to use an reactive approach using Combine like this:

```
 self.pubs = self.dPad!.publisher(for: \GCControllerDirectionPad.xAxis.value)

                self.pubs!.sink { value in
                    log.info("| X-Axis: \(value)")
                }.store(in: &self.cancelBag)
```

The code in the sink-Closure gets called only once when I move my finger on the dPad but then never again at all.

Any ideas why this is the case?